# Jekyll - Google Maps Server API not displaying correct address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jekyll

I am developing a personal webpage using  ***Jekyll*** for a friend and I want to include a dynamic ***google maps*** in order to find a place! So my `_config.yml` is like this :

```
address: Themistokleous 64 Athens 106 81 Greece
```

But the address is not correctly displayed on the website.. anyone knows how should I type the address ?? Thanks in advance

Here is my code on github: https://github.com/kavouras-rempetika/kavouras-rempetika.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `q={% for address in site.address %}{{ address.line }},{% endfor %}` makes reference to an unexisting config variable.

Currently available vars in your *_config.yml* are :

```
location: Athens Greece
address: Themistokleous 64
```

So, you can do :

```
q={{ site.address }},{{ site.location }}
```

Complete iframe is :

```
<iframe id="map_iframe"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    marginheight="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={{ site.google_api_key }}&q={{ site.address }},{{ site.location }}"
    allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

Comment: The problem is the location is not even where the address is on  reality .. I mean I write on address : Athens Greece and it displays New York  ... Is there a specific - standard way to write the address on _config.yml file ? Correct me if I am completely wrong  ? I am new into jekyll

Comment: Have you tried my iframe code ? For me it's working.

Comment: Oh you are right !! I had a typo as i was copying it .. Thank you very much for your time and help-answer !! :-)